# Can you override a sass variable twice, dependant on context?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using the library Bulma for CSS. This comes with default sass variables that can be adjusted. Rather than change it globally I wish to change the value of one such variable to be in one context:

```scss
$table-cell-border: 0;
```

and in another

```scss
$table-cell-border: 1;
```

Is this possible? Do I need to override the underlying CSS instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can achieve this see the example below

```
$primary-color: red;

body {
  background-color: $primary-color; // here red color will get applied.
}

.myClass {
  $primary-color green;
  background-color: $primary-color; // here the green color will get applied
}
```

You can override the value of `variable` inside a scope.